# Multiprocessors and multithreading - Operating Systems

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

I was going through topics of Operating Systems using the text book by Galvin (the 9th edition). In Chapter 4 on multi-threading, I came across problem 14 which is as follows:

A system with two dual-core processors has four processors available for scheduling. A CPU -intensive application is running on this system. All input is performed at program start-up, when a single file must be opened. Similarly, all output is performed just before the program terminates, when the program results must be written to a single file. Between startup and termination, the program is entirely CPU - bound. Your task is to improve the performance of this application by multithreading it. The application runs on a system that uses the one-to-one threading model (each user thread maps to a kernel thread).

• How many threads will you create to perform the input and output? Explain.
• How many threads will you create for the CPU -intensive portion of the application? Explain.

For the first part, I think we could create 4 threads for taking input for reading from a file as well as for writing output to a file. This is because during either input or output, there is no updating of the data being carried out.

For the second part, the nature of operation to be carried out on data is not known, for example, whether  (1) average of the data is to be printed or (2) a function to print the average of first and last data points, then print average of second and second last data points, and so on.

Therefore, for second part, one thread could be employed to handle the operation.

But I am not very sure of the answer I gave here being right. So, I would be very grateful if you could let me know the right answer for this.

Comment: I've never read the Galvin book but judging from the questions asked here, it must be total caca. There is not enough information in the problem to give a correct answer.

Comment: I came across the question, posted the exact same, also wrote what I think should be the answer and asked for correction. I do not understand why it should invite downvotes at all? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is testing if you understand some principles about parallelizing work to increase speed.  Some of these principles are:

- In the usual case, reading and writing a single file cannot be sped up using multiple cores.  Speed of file I/O is determine by the properties of where and how the file is stored.  Throwing more threads at it is not going to help, because those threads are just going to be waiting for the I/O to complete.
- How many threads you use for CPU intensive portion depends entirely on what is being computed.  If the program is generating imagery for a movie, use 4 threads because that is completely parallel.  If the workload is entirely serial, use 1 thread because adding more threads won't help (by definition).

Computing the averages in your example is almost completely parallel, so you should use four threads, not one.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the clarification.